# How I can start a service on my Unix server from windows

Tags: windows, shell, unix, batch-file, batch-processing

I need to stop/start an application service on Unix, while I being on windows. I don't want to do putty and login to unix server and stop service.
What batch script I can write to do this from windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do this manually, make sure you can run the `ssh` command from your batch file (by instaling it and extending your PATH if necessary to where it is installed) and do:

```
ssh root@your-system-name stop service-name
ssh root@your-system-name start service-name
```

This assumes that your linux machine has `start` and `stop` commands, otherwise you might need to invoke `/etc/init.d/service-name stop` or other Linux distro specific command.

Comment: Thanks ..
so it can be like this ..
@echo off
ssh root@my-unix-system
cd /patch to the service stop-start script
stop.sh
pause

Comment: @rickepm if you want to do multiple commands you might have to enclose them in `""` depending on the kind of interpretation that your shell /batch processor does.